# Display Tooltip After Gridview Updates Using Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, gridview, yii

I use yiiGridView javascript function to automatically update a gridview with contacts for every 4 seconds (using setInterval).
When the mouse is over one of the "view", "edit" or "delete" buttons, there is always a tooltip that shows up (I'm using yii bootstrap extension to have a better graphic design for the tooltips). However, when the ajax request updates the gridview, the tooltip disappears and never shows again in google chrome, unless I move the mouse again. In firefox and IE, the tooltip hides but then it automatically shows up again. Is there any function I can call in order to force the tooltip that was displaying to display again if the mouse continues in the same position as before? I guess I would have to call such function in the complete function of yiiGridView right? Can anyone please help me?

Here is the JS code that I use to automatically update the grid view:

```
setInterval(function(){
        $('#contact-grid').yiiGridView('update', {
                data: $(this).serialize(),
                complete: function(jqXHR, status) {

                }
        });
},4000)
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: Using `setInterval()` with ajax is not a good idea due to it's asynchronous nature and de-syncing issues.

Comment: What do you recommend? Thank you.

Comment: Use `setTimeout()` and ajax callback function recursively.

Comment: ajax callback function recursively? Can you give an example please?

Comment: can you post the tooltip code?

Comment: Ivan Buttinoni the tooltip code is the default that comes with the View, Edit and Delete buttons from Yii's grid view: 
<td class="button-column"><a class="view" title="" rel="tooltip" href="/contact/273" data-original-title="View"><i class="icon-eye-open"></i></a>  </td>

Answer (score 4):

You should actually use 'afterAjaxUpdate' in [CGridView](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CGridView)

```
/**
 * @var string a javascript function that will be invoked after a successful AJAX response is received.
 * The function signature is <code>function(id, data)</code> where 'id' refers to the ID of the grid view,
 * 'data' the received ajax response data.
 */
public $afterAjaxUpdate;
```

You can use it like this:

```
<?php
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'id' => 'mygrid',
    'dataProvider' => $dataprovider,
    'afterAjaxUpdate' => 'function(){$(\'[data-toggle="tooltip"]\').tooltip({ html:true, trigger:\'hover\'})}', // <-- this line does the trick!
    'columns' => array(
        'name',
        'address',
        ...
    ),
));
?>
```